# jQuery multiple draggable, one active at the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

How can I do something like this:

I have multiple div elements that are `draggable`. Clicking on one element at the time will apply `draggable` to it, but I want to be able to remove `draggable` if user clicks outside of workspace:

This is what I  have so far:

```js
$("#workzone").on('click', '.item', function() {
    $(this).draggable();
});
```

```html
<div id="workzone" style="height:600px">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

The above works fine partially.

Now I need to remove `draggable` if clicked anywhere within `#workzone` element, and only have one `draggable` element active at the time.

Comment: How can you click on something else if your already dragging?

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery will turn of the draggable() event:

```
$(".item").draggable("disable");
```

So perhaps something like this might solve it:

```
$("#workzone").on('click', '.item', function() {
  $(this).draggable();
  return false;
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $(".item").draggable("disable");
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mfz43u5n/1/

Edit (based on comment): The following jQuery will do the job:

```
$(".item").click(function() {
   $(this).draggable();
   $(".item").not(this).each(function(){
      $(this).draggable("disable");
   });
});

$(document).click(function(event){
   if( $(event.target).closest(".item").length > 0 ) {
    return false;
 } 
   $(".item").draggable("disable");    
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mfz43u5n/3/

Comment: Thank you, but how can I activate only one draggable element at the time? Your example sets multiple dragable. I need on each click only the clicked element to be active and the others disabled.

Comment: @Alko Check the edit. Let me know if you wan't me to explain the code, unless you understand it.

Comment: Thanks this is much better now, except I'm getting an error "Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'"

Comment: Nope, still the same. check  firebug console "Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'"